# Sqlite on Android: select time only from datetime

Tags: sql, sqlite, datetime, select, android-sqlite

I have a date and time (saved as plain TEXT string) in SQLite in following format: YYYYMMDDhhmm (hours and minutes in the end). Can I make a select based on time only - say any day between 18:00 and 20:00?

Comment: Everything in time before 18:00 on a specific day or everything on every day before 18:00 (but not after)?

Comment: I need any (or every :) day... actually I need a time frame, edited question accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extract parts of your datetime stamp with `substr()` and then use regular comparison operators like `<`, `>` or `between` on it. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE SUBSTR(timestampcolumn, 9, 4) BETWEEN '1800' AND '2000';
```

Comment: How can I select multiple time intervals together? Like 1000-1400 AND 1800-2000?

Comment: Just add something like `... OR SUBSTR(...) BETWEEN '1000' AND '1400'`